# Remove an hour from my timestamp

Tags: r, time, strftime

I try to use the strftime function to make readable string from my timestamp. My problem is there is an hour that disapear each time I try to perform the transformation.

I'm in Belgium and it's summertime, so my linux is set to GMT+2

```
jt@jt-roxane:~$ date
lundi 2 juin 2014, 19:18:48 (UTC+0200)

jt@jt-roxane:~$ R

R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)

> Sys.time()
[1] "2014-06-02 19:19:46 CEST"
```

When **my friends** try to convert the timestamp 1401729132, it's correctly translated to

```
as.POSIXct(1401729132, origin="1970-01-01")
"2014-06-02 19:12:12 CEST"
```

But when I try to do it, the answer is

```
> as.POSIXct(1401729132, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2014-06-02 18:12:12 CEST"
```

I tried to set the right timezone, but it don't seem to solve the problem.

```
> strftime(as.POSIXct(1401729132, origin="1970-01-01"), '%H:%M:%S', tz="UTC-2")
[1] "18:12:12"
```

Do you have any idea about where it come from?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:**

I've already tried to set the right TZ in as.POSIXct() - that line give the wrong answer :

```
> as.POSIXct(1401729132, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
[1] "2014-06-02 17:12:12 GMT"
```

Answer (score 4):

Is your friend in the same time zone? Running the same OS?

You should set the timezone parameter (`tz=`) when you do the `as.POSIXct`, not when you do the `strftime`. When you create the date, it will use your local current time zone

```
as.POSIXct(1401729132, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
# "2014-06-02 17:12:12 GMT"
```

Read the `?Sys.timezone` help page on how and why these can vary depending on operating system specific time zone data bases.

Comment: This is likely the trouble.  At my work, we have servers spread around the world, and the clocks are all set to GMT.  Makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Hello, I run under Xubuntu 12.04 and my friend is under ArchLinux, we're both under UTC+2.

Comment: @LoicCoenen Where did you get the number 1401729132 from? Why do you think it's not supposed to be "2014-06-02 17:12:12 GMT"? You get the same result as I do when you set `tz="GMT"`. It seems like that is the correct date/time for that number in that time zone.

Comment: 1401729132 come from a js `Date.now() / 1000`, but with other methods to get timestamp we get the same number - and it was around 19:15 in Belgium (UTC+2). 

So the GMT hour returned is correct, but I can't make it return the correct hour for my timezone.

Comment: When I get the current timestamp from (http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) and try to compute it with R, it still answer the time it was an hour ago.

Comment: @LoicCoenen It sounds like an OS problem then. Try `date -u -d @1401729132` and `date -d @1401729132` on the command line. The first should have hour 17, and the second has your local tz hour. That should match what R is reporting. If it does, then then is not an R issue, this is an OS issue. R decodes the time stamp with your operating system.